# dynamic wiki links using page title to search query on forum

Tags: php, html

I have a wiki and a forum, now I want to place a link in each wiki article that goes to the search page of my forum using the wiki title as search query.

So I guess I need to make a href like this

```
<a href="http://www.myforumsite.com/search/PAGETITLEFROMWIKI">Discuss this topic in forums</a>h
```

Can someone fill in the bits I am missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.myforumsite.com/search/<?php echo url_encode($page_title); ?>">Discuss this topic in forums</a>
```

where $page_title variable with your page title, set by your cms.
or you can use javascript to take title from page on users side

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.myforumsite.com/search/'+document.title+'">Discuss this topic in forums</a>');
```